# How to implement C-like parser in java

Tags: java, parsing, syntax, tokenize

I need to parse C-like scripts (actually Groovy) into several parts, using "(", ")", "&&" and "||" as delimiters like this:

From string

```
(boo == 1 && (foo == null || foo == 0))
```

I need to get some kind of List like this

```
["boo == 1", "&&",  ["foo == null", "||", "foo == 0"]  ]
(list of 3 items, third one is a list too)
```

With "foo == 1" condition it looks easy, but it can be "foo.item(2).contains('abcd') == true" also (condition can contain braces too), and I'm stuck with it.

What is the best way to implement such a parser? Are there any useful libraries or frameworks that can help me? And which one is easier in my case?

Answer (score 1):

The best and cleanest way to implement such a parser goes through using a parser library like JavaCC or ANTLR. With this, you don't only get a list, but even a full syntax tree with entire hierarchy.

Comment: Right now I am reading ANTLR docs, but it looks too complex and hard for my task. Is there an easier way, assuming I don't need full syntax tree?

Comment: Okay, I'm stuck with implementing ANTLR grammar. Could someone give a proper grammar for my case?

Comment: See the grammars for c++ or java, you can remove some of the rules there and make it suitable for you.